# Android list view change text when row is deleted

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a ListView, which has an hidden `button` which become visible on user long click on row.
If someone clicks this button, the row is deleted.

My rows are composed by transactions, and in the same `Activity` i got a `TextView` displaying the amount.

When I add a transaction, my text is changed and the budget updated. My problem is updating it when an user clicks the button and deletes a row.

**here is my adapter class**

```
public class HomePageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TRANSAZIONE> {

    ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE> transazioni;
    public HomePageListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        transazioni = objects;
    }

    TRANSAZIONE transazione;
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_home_page_list, null);

        TextView tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        TextView tvAmou = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        final Button btnElimina = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnElimina);

        transazione = transazioni.get(position);

        String dText = transazione.getDescription();
        String aText = "";
        if(transazione.getAmount() != null) {
            aText = formatter.format(transazione.getAmount()) + " €";
            if (transazione.getAmount() > 0) {
                tvAmou.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                tvAmou.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        tvDesc.setText(dText);
        tvAmou.setText(aText);

        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                btnElimina.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btnElimina.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    btnElimina.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnElimina.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    new TRANSAZIONE().Delete(TRANSAZIONE.class, getContext(), "where id = '" + transazioni.get(position).getId() + "'");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Transazione eliminata.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    transazioni.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore non gestito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

It works properly, and I have no problems updating my layout.

** And this is the method which updates my TextView's text and calls the Adapter. It's in the Activity**

```
public void LoadTotal() throws Exception {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE> transazioni = (ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE>) new TRANSAZIONE().SelectAll(TRANSAZIONE.class, getContext(), "");

    Double totale = Settings.getLimitAmount();

    //prendo solo quelle del mese corrente
    if (transazioni.size() > 0) {
        int numeroAggiornamento = Settings.getResettingDay();

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar transactionDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar lastChangeDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastChangeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numeroAggiornamento);
        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < numeroAggiornamento) {
            lastChangeDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        }

        for (TRANSAZIONE t : transazioni) {
            transactionDate.setTime(t.getDate());

            if (transactionDate.compareTo(lastChangeDate) == -1) {
                transazioni.remove(t);
            } else {
                totale += t.getAmount();
            }
        }
    }
    if (transazioni.size() == 0) {
        transazioni.add(new TRANSAZIONE("Nessuna transazione per il mese in corso.", null, null));
    }
    HomePageListAdapter adapter = new HomePageListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_home_page_list, transazioni);
    lvTransactions.setAdapter(adapter);
    tvBudget.setText(formatter.format(totale));
}
```

My problem is the following:

- When I delete a row, it disappears from the list, but I can't intercept this in my Activity.
- I need someway to call the method *`LoadTotal()`* when my row is deleted.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks all and sorry for my not perfect English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter class

```
public class HomePageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TRANSAZIONE> {
Context context;
    ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE> transazioni;
    public HomePageListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<TRANSAZIONE> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        transazioni = objects;
this.context=context;
    }

    TRANSAZIONE transazione;
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_home_page_list, null);

        TextView tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        TextView tvAmou = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        final Button btnElimina = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnElimina);

        transazione = transazioni.get(position);

        String dText = transazione.getDescription();
        String aText = "";
        if(transazione.getAmount() != null) {
            aText = formatter.format(transazione.getAmount()) + " €";
            if (transazione.getAmount() > 0) {
                tvAmou.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                tvAmou.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        tvDesc.setText(dText);
        tvAmou.setText(aText);

        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                btnElimina.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btnElimina.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    btnElimina.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnElimina.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    new TRANSAZIONE().Delete(TRANSAZIONE.class, getContext(), "where id = '" + transazioni.get(position).getId() + "'");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Transazione eliminata.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    transazioni.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore non gestito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

You can call the method of your activity like

```
((YourActivityName)context).LoadTotal();
```

Comment: Thanks! that's why my method didn't work, i was istantiating a new YourActivityName object.. U saved my day, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way of doing it is by using a `DataSetObserver`.

Inside your activity you have this object:

```
private DataSetObserver adapterObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(){
       // here you call your method
       LoadTotal();
   }
}
```

and then you register/unreguster this observer during onResume/onPause

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   LoadTotal(); // update with latest values
   adapter.registerDataSetObserver(adapterObserver);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(adapterObserver);
}
```

**edit:** some debug info for the op.

here is the code for `notifyDataSetChanged()` from BaseAdapter

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
}
```

and then inside DataSetObservable is simply looping through the list of observers

```
for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   mObservers.get(i).onChanged();
}
```

That means there's very little to actually go wrong there. But it's important to understand what is happening. So my suggestion is to put a breakpoint on all the method calls: onPause, onResume, onChanged and the line you call `notifyDataSetChanged`. And run it with the debugger, so you can see what is being called when and find out why it's not working.

Comment: I tryed to fix this code but it doesn't work, this datasetobserver is never called. I will edit your answer with the fixes i found but it's still not working :(

Comment: that is the same way that the ListView get's notified about changes and updates its statues. I edited the code to put the calls to `super.` that I missed. I typed all by heart and there might be some typos, but I can guarantee that logically it's correct.
Are you, by any chance, calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` when the activity is paused? Then you probably would need an extra call to `LoadTotal()` during `onResume()` to make sure value is up-to-date

Comment: I'm calling the notifydatasetchanged only in the adapter class. I will try to make it work, it seems a better solution :)

Comment: I saw your edits, and they are just typos from answering by heart (I've added them to my answer). My answer is certainly a cleaner approach, as it doesn't depend on specific implementation. If you make it work, please make sure to comment here.

Comment: I simply restarted my app and it worked, but only the first time. From the second time I delete something it doesn't work anymore. I tryed to check on the net but it seems ok, any idea?

Comment: added some debugging tips on my answer. take a read. Also note that I edited my original answer, now it calls `LoadTotal();` during `onResume()` too.